# Inheriting in Android Annotations

Tags: android, inheritance, android-annotations

I have a problem in inheriting from base class when using `AndroidAnnotations`. I have a base Activity named `BaseActivity`:

```
@EActivity
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @ViewById
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @ViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @ViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    NavigationView navView;
}
```

Also i have a child activity named `MainActivity`:

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_main)
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @ViewById
    ImageButton btnTabHome;
}
```

When i build project get following errors:

```
****MyProjectBuildPath****\MainActivity_.java
Error:(82, 13) error: toolbar is not public in BaseActivity; cannot be accessed from outside package

Error:(83, 13) error: drawerLayout is not public in BaseActivity; cannot be accessed from outside package

Error:(84, 13) error: navView is not public in BaseActivity; cannot be accessed from outside package

Error:(90, 9) error: cannot find symbol method initBaseViews()
```

If i inherit from `BaseActivity_`, get following errors:

```
****MyProjectBuildPath****\MainActivity.java
Error:(19, 35) error: cannot find symbol class BaseActivity_

Error:(17, 1) error: org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity can only be used on an element that extends android.app.Activity

Warning:(19, 8) Element packagename.MainActivity invalidated by EActivityHandler
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: have you tried declare scope of variables in BaseActivity to public and then inherit BaseActivity in MainActivty class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding to [androidannotations issues page](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/issues/1933) i should just change modifier of fields.